# LC3 Assembly Language

Tags: lc3

I am trying to write a LC3 assembly language program that takes two input numbers and prints out `x * y = z`.

I can get it to work for numbers `0-9` however any numbers above that I get weird letters or symbols.

Also how can I make it so that it can not only take only 1 inputs per `GETC` but two numbers eg. `10 * 12= 120`?
Any help would be appreciated! :)

Here's what I have done so far

```
    .ORIG x3000
AND R3, R3, #0 ;r3 stores the sum, set r3 to zero
AND R4, R4, #0 ;r4 is the counter
LD R5, INVERSE_ASCII_OFFSET ;inverse ascii offset
LD R6, DECIMAL_OFFSET ;decimal offset
;---------------------
;storing first input digits
LEA R0, display1 ;load the address of the 'display1' message string
PUTS ;Prints the message string
GETC ;get the first number
OUT ;print the first number
ADD R1, R0, #0 ;store input value(ascii) to r1
ADD R1, R1, R5 ;get real value of r1
;storing second input digits
LEA R0, display2 ;load the address of the 'display2' message string
PUTS ;Prints the message string
GETC ;get the first number
OUT ;print the first number
ADD R2, R0, #0 ;store input value(ascii) to r2
ADD R2, R2, R5 ;get real value of r2
;----------------------
ADD R4, R2, #0 ;fill counter with multiplier
MULTIPLICATION:
ADD R3, R3, R1 ;add to sum
ADD R4, R4, #-1 ;decrease counter by one
BRp MULTIPLICATION ;continue loop until multiplier is 0
LEA R0, stringResult
PUTS
ADD R0, R3, R6 ;move result to r0
OUT ;print result
HALT
display1 .STRINGZ "\nenter the 1st no.: "
display2 .STRINGZ "\nenter the 2nd no.: "
stringResult .STRINGZ "\nResult: "
INVERSE_ASCII_OFFSET .fill xFFD0 ; Negative of x0030.
DECIMAL_OFFSET .fill #48
.END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your display function works by adding a number to the base ascii value of `'0'`.  This works because the ascii table was arranged in a way to be convenient. For instance, `'0' + 1 = '1'`, which is equivalent to `0x30 + 1 = 0x31`. However, if you are probably finding that `'0' + 12 = '<'`.  This is because `'0' = 0x30`, so `0x30 + 12 (0xC) = 0x3C`. Looking at the ascii chart we see that `0x3C = '<'`. That is, this is an effective method only to print out a single digit.

The answer to both your questions lie in writing a routine that iteratively deals with digits and forms a number with them. In other words, you will need a loop that determines which character to print out next and prints it.

Comment: Can you take a look at this? http://superuser.com/questions/904324/which-of-the-following-instructions-can-reference-a-memory-location-that-is-100